# req is not defined node js

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, express, mssql

estoy haciendo una web en nodejs y mi código me dice que req no esta definido, este es mi código:

permisos.js

```
const permisos = async(palabraClave) => {
    let permisosUsuario = req.session.usuario.permisos.split(',');
    let token = req.session.usuario.token;


    let permisoUrl = async() => {
        await sql.connect(config);
        let db = new sql.Request();
        db.input("palabra", sql.VarChar(100), palabraClave);
        db.input("token", sql.VarChar(100), token);
        let result = await db.execute('VER_CODIGO_PALABRA');
        return result.recordset[0];
    }

    return permisoUrl().then(permiso => {
        for (let i = 0; i < permisosUsuario.length; i++) {
            if (permisosUsuario[i] == permiso.resultado) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`error al sacar los permisos necesarios para ${palabraClave}, ${err}`);
        return res.status(404).redirect('/404');
    });

}



module.exports = {
    permisos
};
```

y en mi código donde gestiono las rutas llamo a la función de la siguiente manera:

usuarios.js

```
app.get("/editarUsuario", login, (req, res) => {

    permisos('editarUsuarioDatos').then(acceso => {
        if (!!acceso == false) {
            return res.status(404).redirect('/404');
        } else {
            return res.render("nuevo-usuario.hbs");
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error al sacar los permisos', err);
        return res.status(404).redirect('/404');
    });
});
```

Al ir a la ruta me dice que req is not defined, pero ya lo tengo definido cuando llamo a la url en el app.get, como podría hacer que mi código detectase el req pudiendo pasarle el argumento de palabraClave?? Muchas gracias

Comment: Como bien dices lo defines al momento de realizar la llamada mediante `get`, pero también lo estás usando en la función *permisos* y es ahí donde no lo tienes definido

Comment: Y como puedo defirnirlo?? al poner (req, res, next, palabraClave) no funciona

Comment: ¿Y para qué pasar todo el objeto `req`, cuándo sólo usas `permisoUsuario` y `token`? Puedes definir tu método para que reciba dichos parámetros: `const permisos = async(permisoUsuario, token, palabraClave) { ... }`. Por otro lado, tienes algunas otras cosas que podrías ajustar en tu código. Saludos

Comment: Esto: `return permisoUrl().then(permiso => { ... }).catch(...);` no hace lo que crees que hace. No es la forma correcta de trabajar ni devolver resultados de procesos asíncronos.

Comment: Primero, en cuanto al primer comentario tienes razón, al ser pocos valores lo puedo pasar así y segundo, porque el return permisoUrl().then().catch() no debería usarlo para procesos asíncronos?? Muchas gracias